# Kofax Capture 8.0 - Document Separation Problems

Tags: kofax

I have a batch class (KC8) which is using page/form recognition and separator zones ("Page 1 of" = separator value). It seems like about 50% of the time it will improperly separate the documents, with some not even getting the correct form type, and others breaking off pages 1, 2 and 3 and 4 into 3 separate documents when they should only be one. Of course all of this gets to the Quality Control queue, but when you unreject them they seem to process and release with no problems. Why is this happening? Shouldn't they continuously fail to be recognized and separated properly if they failed the first time? Does anyone have any similar experience or advice for fixing it? Please ask any questions you need to clarify the details of the batch class if you need it.

Thanks,

- Matt

Comment: Thanks for the downvote 5 years later. real helpful.  Maybe next time leave a comment so we know why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the separation issue.  Part of the problem was a form id zone located in a place on the form that moved around depending on how much information was entered into one of the fields near the top of the page.  Obviously pages like that would not be recognized.  I picked a different recognition zone (company logo + text image) that did not move around and everything is fine now.

Comment: Recognition zone is available in  'Administration' or KTM?

Comment: It should be a standard feature in the Administration module.